# doctrine2 : intervert attributes with 1To1 relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, unit-of-work, one-to-one, flush

I am facing a problem here while coding a symfony2 application.

Situation:
I want to create a copy of an entity "A" and then modify its attribute "foo". However, A and Foo are related by a OneToOne relationship, which triggers an error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '9' for key 
UNIQ_41A6A445D7FA9592
```

My entities are as follow:

```
/**
 * AcmeBundle\Entity\A
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AcmeBundle\Entity\ARepository")
 */

class A
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */    
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Mvcc\AcmeBundle\Entity\Foo")
    * 
    */ 
    protected foo;

    getFoo(){
        return $this->foo;
    }

    setFoo($foo){
        $this->foo = $foo;
        return $this;
    }          


}
```

Issue:
in my controller I do the following:

```
/*start*/
/*1) I create a clone aBis of a, instance of A.its foo attribute is connected to foo1.*/
$aBis = clone($a);
/*2) I modify the attribute foo for a */
$foo2 = new Foo();
$a->setFoo($foo2);
$em->persist($foo2)
$em->persist($aBis);
$em->persist($a);
$em->flush();

/*end*/
```

I guess that, when it comes to flushing, the fact that at some point both "a" and "aBis" have the attribute foo1 does not let doctrine to continue and see that $a changed its attribute to a new foo.
Do you have an idea how to solve this?

My actual problem is a little more complex (it involves deeper relationships and the unit of work). however, I think I summarized the main issue here.

Many Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone an entity with relationships, implement the `public function __clone()` in all entities which are involved

Example in your **entity**:

```
public function __clone()
{
    if ($this->id) {
        // if the $foo property is a ManyToMany, ManyToOne or OneToMany
        $foo = $this->getFoo();
        $this->foo = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($foo as $row) {
            $this->foo[] = $row;
        }
        // if the $foo property is a OneToOne
        $foo = $this->getFoo();
        $this->foo = clone $foo;
    }
}
```

In your **controller**:

```
$myOriginal = new A();
$myClone = clone $myOriginal;
// then persist
$em->persist($myClone);
// and flush
$em->flush();
```

**OneToMany** implementation of your entity:

```
/**
 * AcmeBundle\Entity\A
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AcmeBundle\Entity\ARepository")
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */    
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mvcc\AcmeBundle\Entity\Foo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="foo_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */ 
    protected foo;

    getFoo(){
        return $this->foo;
    }

    setFoo($foo){
        $this->foo = $foo;
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pi Wi,thanks. It works but in my configuration, it creates an indesirable clone. the exact config is sth like:

Comment: Can you give us a more detailed explanation what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the cut explanation.

Comment: we have A1->foo1 . I want to clone A1 (into A2), and then modify A1. I would like to avoid having "foo1" twice in database, which happens when I follow your example. if possible (in order to avoid surpopulating my database), I would like to "connect" the clone A2 to the existing foo1.    At last, (this is additional complexity), this is a bidirectional relationship:     A <--> Foo

Comment: That isn't possible with an OneToOne relationship. Use a ManyToOne <-> OneToMany relationship instead

Comment: Ok thanks. I will have a look for a slightly different design and report if I can bypass my issue.

Comment: As it happens, I have the issue for a oneToMany as well. I will check on it and come back rapidly

Comment: Don't implement de public function __clone() if you don't want to clone the relationships